# How to apply a theme to different activities in android studio?

Tags: android

I want to have different images as the background. Each time the user changes the theme, the background will change. The changes should be applied in different activities of the application. Any guy can help me?

Answer (score 0):

create a `map` with `key/value` , each key has background image as value . key is the id of the theme

```
Map map = new LinkedHashMap(); 

    map.put(1,R.drawable.back1);
    map.put(2,R.drawable.back2);
    map.put(3,R.drawable.back3);
```

so if the user select theme one that has the id 1 :

```
int image = map.get(1) ;
```

`image` is your int resource for the image and then you can set the background with it

Answer (score 0):

1 - create application class :

```
public class App extends Application {
```

2 - declare it in AndroidManifest.xml i Application tag :

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
```

3 - in application class create variable to store your image id

```
public class App extends Application {
  public static int selectedImageId;
```

4 - set activity layout background in onCreate of the activities